# Visual Studio for Web 2013 cant see all files in solution explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Basically I don't know if i'm being an idiot but i'm trying to use ASP MVC 4 inside visual studio 2013, now I would like to edit files which are not displaying in the solution explorer:

[image]

so like in the picture, I have in here a Global and Content folder in the Windows Explorer, now the Content folder you can see in both Windows Explorer and Solution Explorer, however  I have my own files and folders in there and they are not displaying.

Also in the scripts folder all my scripts I made are not displaying in the solution explorer.

The entire of my Important folder is missing too.

How can I show them as you can see them inside Windows Explorer.

Thanks

Comment: third icon from the right in solution explorer at the top. Click it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer at the top (make sure you have a project selected), click the Show All Files button (looks like two piece of paper with the dashed outline of a third piece of paper). Then you can right click the files that aren't showing up and click "Include In Project". Then you can click the Show All Files button again if you want.

The Show All Files button shows/hides files that are within the project folder, whether or not they're added to the project's `.csproj`.

The Include In Project button adds the file to the `.csproj` file. If it's already in the project, you would have the Exclude From Project option which removes the file from the `.csproj`.

Comment: This  is weird if you look on my image the icon doesn't exist, now I've accidentaly done something to make it appear. I have no idea but now I've clicked it and it works...

Comment: @Matthew it does exist, you have to select your project or something in it. In your screenshot you have your solution highlighted.

Comment: @Matthew I've noticed the icon doesn't appear for Web Site projects, but if you have any other project active the icon will appear.

Comment: Yeah I was clicked in the incorrect place, I completely understand now. It's why all the similar questions didn't make much sense to me :)